# pickle.load() gives invalid load key, '\x9c' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, pickle, python-3.8

##### I am trying to pickle.load() a cache binary file but it keeps on giving invalid key errors.

**My code**

```py
import pickle
filename = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Project\cache\sample'
file = open(filename, "rb")
pickle_time = pickle.load(file)
print(pickle_time)
```

**The error**

```
get key 'filename.df' -> invalid load key, '\x9c'.
```

I tried pickle.load on some other binary files written on someone else's computer and it worked fine, it's only throwing this issue when I pickle.load() binary files writen on my system.

I write using flask-cache

```py
from flask_caching import Cache

# app is a dash app
cache = Cache(
        config={
            'CACHE_TYPE': 'FileSystemCache',
            'CACHE_DIR': os.path.join(os.getenv('DASH_CACHE'), 'cache', 'my_data'),
            'CACHE_THRESHOLD': 0,
            'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 24 * 60 * 60
        }
    )
    

cache.init_app(app.server)

u_id='0000'
ps='system0000'
session_id = u_id + '___' + ps + '___' +datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')

# RH is an internal class for reading data from DB and performing post processing
df = RH.GeneratePriceJSON(lat, lng, 15,currency=currency, no_limit=False)
df = json.dumps(df)

@app.callback(
[Output('some-value', 'children')],
[Input('some-url', 'search')],
)
def foo(some_url):
    with app.server.app_context():
        cache.set(session_id + '.' + 'df', df)
        df = session_id + '.' + 'df'
    return df
```

Comment: Show us how that file was written.

Comment: "I tried pickle.load on some other binary files written on someone else's computer and it worked fine, it's only throwing this issue when I pickle.load() binary files writen on my system." Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm confused here. Are you under the impression that `pickle.load()` should be able to make sense out of **any** binary file? If so, why? What is "a cache binary file", and where did it come from?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I assumed that because I was using flask-cache and it worked fine on other PCs which ran the same code, it even runs fine in production. I have updated the question with how I write the binary file.

Comment: @JohnGordon added the code to show how I write files using flask-cache

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the invalid load key issue: it was the Flask-Caching version, 1.11.1 throws the error, resolved by downgrading to 1.10.1

```python
pip install Flask-Caching==1.10.1
```

[Original Answer](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-caching/issues/221#issuecomment-1140559960)